# CSS - overflow - scrollbar scrolls too much

Tags: html, css

My page is 1920px width, and for some unknown to me reason, my scrollbar wants to scroll page into the right, where there is empty space only. I tried specifying `<html style="width: 1920px;">` but that does nothing, bottom scrollbar just scrolls like the page was 2100px... Is there anything I can do about it? Like, specifying fixed horizontal overflow?

**Edit:** Here is the link to the page: look only at homepage, because on the other pages it looks ok: `http://scyk.pl`

Comment: Post your html and css where possible, it'll help us get a better idea of what's wrong.

Comment: can you create an example for better understanding of your problem & it's not good to define width to **html** tag

Comment: can you display more html about your problem please ?

Comment: Edited my post with link. :)

Comment: Make sure the padding and margin of your html and body added together with the width don't exceed the width you want, otherwise try adding the following: css box-sizing:border-box (newer browsers only)

Comment: can you put your code in jsfiddle

Comment: @Pete: where should I put that code? I put that as a style in `<html>` or in `<body>`, and didn't work (I am using newest chrome)

Comment: its easy if you post whole code or part of your code

Comment: @AshReva: I posted a link to my page. :)

Comment: `.frontPageButtons` is your problem - it is 100% width but you are margin it left 30% - which causes it to stick out to the side

Comment: its very difficult looking at your link. how will i know what have you used. Do you want us to read the page source. Its very hard. Also refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987261/how-to-stop-horizontal-scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in the buttons bar you have to look in your code for :

```
<div class="frontPageButtons">
```

the position of the div is relative and you set left to 30% :

```
.frontPageButtons {
    left: 30%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Tried it just now, with no results. :/

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a child element that is pushing the containing block wider. Overflow hidden will work, but generally it is better to avoid setting fixed widths for child elements unless you are defining a new layout context.

Answer (score 0):

try to set `min-height:500px;` in css

happy coding...